# How to extract values from the button in listbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox

I am trying to create a sports news app. I've created one button inside the listbox which shows all the News,description,etc. There are no. of buttons depends on xml file. When i click on the button i want to show the News and description from that button on the the next page. how do i do that? Thanks

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstShow" FontFamily="Arial Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"
   Margin="-6,0,0,-26" Height="610" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
   Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="0.8">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Button Width="450" Height="Auto" Background="Black" 
                  BorderBrush="Transparent" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="23" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5" 
                  Opacity="0.95" Click="news_click" Foreground="White">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Imageurl}" Width="200" Height="Auto"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock   TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP Black" 
                          Foreground="White" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" Width="350" 
                          Height="150">
                        <Run FontSize="23" Text="{Binding News}" />
                        <LineBreak/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Desc}" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="16" 
                          FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight"/>
                        <LineBreak/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Newsurl}" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="16" 
                          FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight"/>

                     </TextBlock>
                  </StackPanel>
               </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
myData = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
// var data = myData.Descendants("headlines").FirstOrDefault();
var data1 = from query in myData.Descendants("headlinesItem")
    where query.Element("images").Descendants("imagesItem").Any()
    select new UpdataNews
    {
        News = (string)query.Element("headline").Value,
        Desc = (string)query.Element("description"),
        Newsurl = (string)query.Element("links").Element("mobile").Element("href"),
        Imageurl = (string)query.Element("images").Element("imagesItem").Element("url"),
    };
lstShow.ItemsSource = data1;
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to show it in the next page? What are you using? What's your question exactly?

Comment: I want to pass these values related to the text block (button) to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways.

1. If you use MVVM, the best way is to set a Command on your button and set the CommandParameter to the binding.

   <Button Command={Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" ...
2. If you don't use MVVM you can do this:

   <Button Tag="{Binding}" Click="My_Click_Event" ...

Then in the code behind just do:

```
public void My_Click_Event(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var o = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to get those values from the listbox?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You can use the methods I described in your Listbox's DataTemplate.

Comment: it worked thanks. But i have multiple values in my list, using button i can only get one value, so any suggestions?

Comment: If you use {Binding} it should pass the whole object to your code, then you can take whatever properties you wish.